# What does it mean by “seat-of-the-pants”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading a book. It is related to business continuity management. What does it mean by "“**seat-of-the-pants**” in following sentence?

> His organization had not conducted a formal BCP process, and he was
> confident that a “seat-of-the-pants” approach would work fine in the
> unlikely event of a disaster.

Comment: Anyone who report my question pls tell me why these questions are not off-topic?
[1]: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175586/what-does-reached-down-into-the-barrel-and-claim-to-notoriety-mean?rq=1
[2]: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175586/what-does-reached-down-into-the-barrel-and-claim-to-notoriety-mean?rq=1

Comment: somehow answer is in satisfactory level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something by the seat of the pants is to do something by relying on your instincts rather than by a formal procedure or set of rules. The term originated in flying, where pilots receive physical sensations from their seat caused by their plane's movement. Some pilots would 'fly by the seat of their pants' rather than rely on instruments. This can be dangerous in some situations because the sensations can be misleading. There can be a negative implication of recklessness, over-confidence, or lack of due care.

[Seat-of-the-pants (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seat-of-the-pants)